# Whitelist nested properties using this particular object format

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

need "whitelist" object to look like this:

```
{
    a: {
        b: {
            c: ''
        }
    }
}
```

apply to:

```
{
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 1
        }
        d: 2
        e: 3
    }
}
```

result:

```
{
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 1
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Not sure how to implement this using underscore. Was looking at _.pick but ran into trouble with the nesting.

Comment: The whole point of SO is to post the code you ran into trouble with, not for us to do the work for you. Share your code if you want help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion with `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
function getPaths(obj, whiteList) {  
  return Object.keys(whiteList)
    .reduce(function(whiteObj, key) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      } else if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        whiteObj[key] = getPaths(obj[key], whiteList[key]);
      } else {
        whiteObj[key] = obj[key];
      }
    
      return whiteObj;
    }, {})
}

var whiteList = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: ''
    }
  },
  g: ''
};

var obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1
    },
    d: 2,
    e: 3
  }
};

var result = getPaths(obj, whiteList);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function like this:

```
function filter_nested_properties_in_object(allowed_properties, original_object) {
    if (_.contains(['boolean', 'number', 'string'], typeof original_object))
        return original_object;
    var filtered_object = {};
    _.each(allowed_properties, function(allowed_value, property_name) {
        var original_value = original_object[property_name];
        if (original_value !== undefined)
            filtered_object[property_name] = filter_nested_properties_in_object(
                allowed_value, original_value);
    });
    return filtered_object;
}
```

Pass your "whitelist object" as `allowed_properties` and the object to which you want to apply it to as `original_object`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating custom function, one way to do it is to use standard built-in object methods such as JSON.stringify and JSON.parse. JSON.stringify accepts three arguments (value, replacer?, space?). Replacer can either be a custom node visitor function or an array which whitelist the property keys. Based on the above information, the following code will achieve what you want to accomplish:

```
var obj= {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 1
        },
        d: 2,
        e: 3
    }
};
var tempstr=JSON.stringify(obj.a,['b']);
var newobj=JSON.parse(tempstr);
obj.a=newobj;
```

obj // should now give you the whitelisted object